# Filter by a calculated colum in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to SELECT columns for which the difference in days exceeds 50.

However I am unable to do so. Find below my query:

```sql
SELECT name_,
       client_p as Client,
       to_date(first_date)-to_date(last_day) as difference
FROM   table1.mydata
where  difference>50
```

any insights on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference it that way; either use this

```
SELECT name_,
       client_p AS client,
       TO_DATE (first_date) - TO_DATE (LAST_DAY) AS difference
  FROM table1.mydata
 WHERE TO_DATE (first_date) - TO_DATE (LAST_DAY) > 50;
```

or - with your query as a CTE (or a subquery):

```
WITH
   temp
   AS
      (SELECT name_,
              client_p AS client,
              TO_DATE (first_date) - TO_DATE (LAST_DAY) AS difference
         FROM table1.mydata)
SELECT *
  FROM temp
 WHERE difference > 50;
```

---

Note that you should store dates as `DATE`s, not strings - which is what `TO_DATE` function suggests.

But, if you do store them as strings, then you should provide format model to the `TO_DATE` function. It is unknown which format you do have, but - you should know it.

On the other hand, if you store dates as you should (in `DATE` datatype columns), then remove `TO_DATE` from your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias to filter right away. Either make a subquery and select from that using the alias or change to:

```
SELECT name_,
       client_p as Client,
       to_date(first_date)-to_date(last_day) as difference
FROM   table1.mydata
where  to_date(first_date)-to_date(last_day) > 50
```